# OpenERP 7.0 python 2.7 OS windows 7

Tags: odoo

I installed OpenERP 7.0, Eclipse 4.2, and Python 2.7 in Windows 7.

Followed step by step tutor, of how to make a new module in OpenERP, yet am keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140227-001259\Server\server\openerp\addons\student\student.py", line 1, in <module>
from osv import osv
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140227-001259\Server\server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 28
import IntegrityError, OperationalError, errorcodes
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: i think you need to provide your code it clearly says indent giving error, python is sensitive to indentation please check and tidy up your coding again exactly as the tutorial provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation error , Python support one tab after you define a class , or function , then with a class one tab for name , cloumns etc and the same in functions. i hope you understand now , its not confusing :)

Answer (score 1):

Indent is usually a space error or tab, python indent consists of 4 spaces only, double check line 27,28